# Passing arrays to php page

Tags: php, ajax, arrays, xmlhttprequest, nodelist

I've been struggling on how to solve this. I wasn't able to find any solutions over the internet.

This a part of the code:

```
var params = "nome=" + encodeURI(document.getElementById("nome").value )+
"&email=" + encodeURI(document.getElementById("email").value )+
"&telefone=" + encodeURI(document.getElementById("telefone").value )+
"&produto=" + encodeURI(document.getElementsByName("produto[]") )+
"&quantidade=" + encodeURI(document.getElementsByName("quantidade[]") )+
"&msg=" + encodeURI(document.getElementById("msg").value );
xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
```

"produto" and "quantidade" are arrays, coming from a form. How to pass this values to my php page (I want to send the content via email).

Comment: HTML Forms doesn't have arrays. Could you elaborate on what you're trying to accomplish, perhaps show us your HTML?

Comment: if they are check boxes it could be passed to php as an array I believe

Comment: what are the form elements that have the names `produto[]` and `quantidade[]`

Answer (score 2):

using jquery the `serialize()` function will turn your array into a string to pass to your server

```
$('[name=produto]').serialize()
```

http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: Far easier to let jquery handle the form serialization/ajax stuff than trying to roll your own. +1.

Comment: That's great, using serialize makes it way simple! Awesome, my application is working like a charm now. Thank you guys for the replies.

Answer (score 0):

I briefly remember if you do this: (this is also how jQuery serialize works)

```
var myArrayToPost = [1, 2, 3];
var postString = "";
for(<-- Iterate over myArrayToPost -->) {
   postString += "MyArray[]=" + value + "&";
}
<-- Post postString -->
```

Basically you want the post to be this:

```
"MyArray[]=FirstValue&MyArray[]=SecondValue&MyArray[]=ThirdValue"
```

Then PHP will automatically put that into an array in `$_POST` so you can get it:

```
$_POST['MyArray'] // which will equal 
                  // array(
                  //   'FirstValue',
                  //   'SecondValue', 
                  //   'ThirdValue'
                  // );
```

Answer (score 0):

When you pass parameters in http request, each one of them is a pair name=value, so produto=1 is a parameter produto with 1 as its value. To take an "array" from http request you must build the several parameters with same name, something like produto=1&produto=2& ...

Comment: Ademir, acabei optando pelo "serialize", muito simples e funcional, obrigado.

Comment: Não conhecia esta solução, creio que vou adotar também, abraços Paulo.